# How to get entitymanager to work with GWT Maven project?

Tags: maven, gwt, jpa, eclipselink, entitymanager

I've created a maven based GWT project.
So far I've added the JPA facet, managed to generate entities from the connected database.

But in my java source code when I attempt to create an EntityManager, I receive the following error.

> [ERROR] [project] - Line 17: No source code is available for type javax.persistence.EntityManager; did you forget to inherit a required module?

Any help to solving this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you configure your build path properly? If you use Eclipse, check if `EclipseLink` is in your build path.

Comment: Yes, eclipselink is under my maven dependencies.

Comment: I remember now, EclipseLink should be in war/WEB-INF/lib, too. Maybe that's missing.

Answer (score 0):

`EclipseLink` should be in build path and under `war/WEB-INF/lib`. Latter is used when you run your built project.

Comment: Actually I've found out now that what I want to do, is impossible the way I thought. Basically I want to connect to a sybase database from my GWT project. So what I actually need to know, is how to use GWT RequestFactory to make the connection.

Comment: Then I think you should ask a new question accordingly.

Comment: Yeah no worries, thanks anyways. I'll first check if someone else has asked the same question.